# selectItems of selectOneMenu with param in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf, parameters, jsf-2

I have dynamically generated form therefore i can't directly take data for my jsf components. I wander if there is a way to get selectItems with param transferred to method?
for example:

and it will be invoke getItems(String a) method

or may be use  somehow.

Is it possible? Is there other ways to parametrize getters and setters?

Comment: It's hard to visualize what you've as far. Some code would help to get better insights and thus give better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the method directly, rather than relying on the javabeans property naming convention.

ie. rather than:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{someBean.list}" />
```

do:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{someBean.getList(myparamter)}" />
```

Where the `getList` method of your backing bean takes an argument.

Comment: Noted should be that this only works out the box on Servlet 3.0 / JSP 2.2 containers. Otherwise you've got to replace the EL implementation by for example JBoss EL. I am however not convenient that this is "the" answer to OP's *actual* problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can help you.

All you need to do is a

```
public class SomeBean{
  public List<SelectItem> getList(){
    List<ItemType> list = getItemsFromSomewhereElse();
    List<SelectItem> resultList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    for (ItemType it : list){
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem(it.getKey(), it.getValue()); 
        resultList.add(item);
    }
    return resultList;
  }
}
```

on xhtml you do this:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectItem"
 value="#{someBean.itemThatIsGoingToBeFilled}">
  <f:selectItems
   value="#{someBean.list}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

There`s a [Small tutorial](http://www.exadel.com/tutorial/jsf/jsftags-guide.html) here.